# JSON Stringify One Object Per Line

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to stringify the following into the expected output?

Input:

```
let output = JSON.stringify([
   {
     "Color": "Red", 
     "Type":"Fast"
   },
   {
     "Color": "Blue", 
     "Type":"Slow"
   }
]);
```

Expected output:

```
[
   {"Color": "Red", "Type":"Fast"},
   {"Color": "Blue", "Type":"Slow"}
]
```

Comment: There isn't lots of control over the formatting of JSON. It's not normally important.

Comment: You can either get multi-line output by using the optional indent argument, or you can get it all on a single line. There's no way to say that arrays should be spread over lines, but objects should be one line.

Comment: But why? What is your goal? JSON is designed to be a transport text structure. Why do you need a transport structure to be 'pretty'. If this is for debugging or making code to look nice, then use an IDE to solve this.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I do have an IDE that easily solves this, however, the output isn't for me. It is for an intended user.

Comment: @Barmar I agree.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. Rarely do.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Sorry, just came back to a lot of downvotes and was surprised. To explain a little further, this was more of an exploratory question. The intents were to make it easy for someone to copy and paste dynamic JSON configs.

Comment: glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try mapping through each item individually and stringifying, then joining together by a linebreak:

```js
const arr = [
   {"Color": "Red", "Type":"Fast"},
   {"Color": "Blue", "Type":"Slow"}
];

const result = "[\n" + arr.map(e => '  ' + JSON.stringify(e)).join(',\n') + "\n]";

console.log(result)
```